# How can I write this using Matlab with for loop, ones, and zeros?

Tags: matlab

Please help me out with this code:

```
for i = 1:n
      u(t - a_i - td_i);
end
```

where:

`u`: step function

`t`: time vector with `n` elements

`a_i`, `tau_i`, and `td_i`: variables that change inside `for` loop

---

I guess I need to use `zeros` and `ones`, but how can I do this correctly?

Comment: What is a "step" function?  Do you mean the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Discrete_form)?

Comment: And you want to add them up or make a function that takes t as a parameter?

Comment: What do you want the output to be? A vector sampled at equidistant time points? And what is `tau_i`?

Comment: actually, the time vector t is fixed, then for each triplet (a_i, tau_i, td_i) i need to recompute the vector u(t-.....) in such way it must have the same size of t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple function to sum the value inside the loop:

```
func = @(t) sum(t > a + td)
```

func(t) will be the sum of the foor loop

Comment: i don't want sum, i want generate the heaviside vector with changing parameters

Comment: But that's the same thing basically, just without the sum. that very simple thing t - a - td returns a vector, so depending how you define the actual zero you can use larger than or larger than or equal zero. Or if you actually want the heaviside function, which equals 1/2 at zero, you can use the normal heaviside function in matlab: heaviside(t-a-td)

Comment: thanks for reminding me the built-in function heaviside